# freemarker: is there a way i can be aware of the calling url?

Tags: html, freemarker

I have a nav that gets loaded into the page by a freemarker `<#macro>` tag. The nav is the same on every page, but I would like the link(page) that the user is currently looking at to be a different color. I know how to change the color and all that, the thing that is getting me is how can freemarker access the url (to know what page the nav is filling)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeMarker itself is Web-unaware, so what such information it can access is completely up to the Web Application Framework designers. Usually, the Web Application Framework puts some variables into the FreeMarker data-model to access Web-related stuff (like, you might have `request.url` or something).

Comment: thanks... i haev a rc.contextPath which gives me the url... thanks for pointing me in the right direction